# Jquery textfield sorting

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to sort the text fields using jquery?
I want to sort the values in the text field. I couldn't use grids. I need to do it in Jquery.

```
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" value="5">
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" value="3">
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" value="6">
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" value="1">
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" value="9">
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" value="8">
</label></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I want to sort the text fields as 1,3,5,6,8,9 (ASC order).
I couldn't find the solution. Please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: You can change `value` manually & give the corresponding `label`, right? I mean its just the value of the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mylist = $('table');
var listitems = mylist.find('input[type=text]');
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).val();
   var compB = $(b).val();
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks. But the appearance changed. How to maintain the appearance as it is. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give them ids then iterate through the DOM using the `each()` function, whilst using a sorting algorithm.